# plot_covariate_groups does not work with feature in strats

Tags: python, python-3.x, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I built the Cox Proportional Hazard model with strata features.

I needed information about the feature in strata. For this I used `plot_partial_effects_on_outcome()` or `plot_covariate_groups()`, but theres an error, that this feature is not in original dataset, but it's not true. Original dataset (data_strata) in my case HAS this feature ('Partner').

What I am doing wrong? How can I find information about feature in strata?

```
strata = ['Partner','OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'TotalCharges_strata', 'InternetServiceFunctions_strata']
cph.fit(data_strata,"tenure",event_col="Churn", strata = strata)
cph.plot_covariate_groups('Partner', values=[0, 1])
```

```
KeyError: 'covariate `Partner` is not present in the original dataset'
```

I expected the graphs with differents values of my feature and curves based in this value.

I checked columns in original dataset and unique values:

```
data_strata.columns
```

```
Index(['gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents', 'tenure',
       'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity',
       'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV',
       'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod',
       'MonthlyCharges', 'Churn', 'TotalCharges_strata',
       'InternetServiceFunctions_strata'],
      dtype='object')
```

```
data_strata['Partner'].unique()
```

```
array([1, 0])
```

What's wrong?